# Wishlist Share controller url is wrong in Magento 2?

Tags: customer-account, wishlist, magento2.3.4, account-dashboard, share-wishlist

I want to share my wishlist with anyone But When I am clicking on Share wishlist button then it is redirecting to wrong controller URL.

```
https://example.com/wishlist/index/index/wishlist_id/12/
```

It must be redirected to Share controller URL must be like: `https://example.com/wishlist/index/share/wishlist_id/12/`

Answer (score 0):

To add wishlist controller path must be like :
http://localhost//wishlist/index/add/

To view list of wishlist item path must be like below:
http://localhost//wishlist/index/index/wishlist_id/5/

Comment: I want to share so When I am clicking share wishlist button then it redirects to this url:  https://example.com/wishlist/index/index/wishlist_id/12/        

It must be redirect to this URL:    https://example.com/wishlist/index/share/wishlist_id/12/